# Нужны ли запятые в предложении с "благодаря Вам"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Благодаря Вам(,) я полюбила математику.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Благодаря Вам я полюбила математику.***

Обороты с предлогом ***благодаря*** могут обособляться, но в данном случае это не требуется, поскольку оборот не распространен, находится в начале предложения и не разбивает подлежащее и сказуемое.

> *Но благодаря ей будет спасено от голода целое семейство.* Н. Тэффи, Предсказатель прошлого.
> *Благодаря Николаю Матвеичу я выучил название всех гор...* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Зеленые горы.

[**БЛАГОДАРЯ (кому, чему)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_56) (Грамота.ру)
[**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОГАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1) (Грамота.ру)

Answer (score 1):

Запятая не требуется. 'Благодаря" — в вашем случае предлог и не выделяется интонационно.